# How do you pass in the value from collection_select to onchange function in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to pass in the value selected from my collection_select drop down to an onchange function. When I do name, my value prints out as *source[index]*, but I want the value of this not that as the text itself.

```
<%= collection_select(:source, :index, @sources, :id, :name, options = {include_blank: "Please select a source..."}, html_options = {:onchange => "updateTextArea(name)"}) %>

function updateTextArea(source){
 var value = source;
 console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
html_options = {:onchange => "updateTextArea()"}

function updateTextArea() {
  console.log($(this).val());
}
```

Comment: that gives me the following error - undefined local variable or method `name'

Comment: still no luck - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: Try to use `select_tag` instead.

Comment: How will that change how I pass in a value to the function?

Comment: The solution was to use "this.value" for the argument in the onchange function.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the argument from "name" to "this.value" solved my problem.

```
<%= collection_select(:source, :index, @sources, :id, :name, options = {include_blank: "Please select a source..."}, html_options = {:onchange => "updateTextArea(this.value)"}) %>

function updateTextArea(source){
 var value = source;
 console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be an example in below:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:id, index.sources, :id, :name,options = {include_blank: "Please select a source..."}, html_options = {:onchange => "updateTextArea(name)"})  %> #-> f is a form tag this you use this form
```

Hope will help you

Comment: what if I am not using a form? this is a stand alone drop down.

Comment: That is what I have done in my question. I am able to get the drop down to display correctly. However, the value passed into the onchange function is not printing out the value chosen in drop down.